# Intermittent timeouts between AWS Lambda and RDS

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

We are currently experiencing what I can only describe as **random intermittent** timeouts between AWS Lambda and RDS. After deploying our functions and running them successfully, they can randomly switch to a state of timing out *with no configuration changes*. Important to note, we are also monitoring the DB connections and can confirm that we aren't running into a max connection issue.

Here are the details on our setup:

Code being executed (using Node.JS v. 6.10):

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

exports.dbWrite = (events, context, callback) => {

   const db = mysql.createConnection({
       host: <redacted>,
       user: <redacted>,
       password: <redacted>,
       database: <redacted>
   });

   db.connect(function (err) {
       if (err) {
           console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
           return;
       }

       console.log('connected !');
   });

   db.end();

};
```

We are using the Node.JS `mysql` library, v. 2.14.1.

From a networking perspective:

- The Lambda function is in the same VPC as our RDS instance
- The Lambda function has subnets assigned, which are associated with a routing table that **does not** have internet access (not associated with an internet gateway)
- The RDS database is **not** publicly accessible.
- A security group has been created and associated with the Lambda function that has wide open access on all ports (for now - once DB connectivity is reliable, that will change).
- The above security group has been whitelisted on port 3306 within a security group associated with the RDS instance.

CloudWatch error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Connection._handleConnectTimeout 
     (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:419:13)",
     "Socket.g (events.js:292:16)",
     "emitNone (events.js:86:13)",
     "Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)",
     "Socket._onTimeout (net.js:338:8)",
     "ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)",
     "tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)",
     "Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)",
     "    --------------------",
     "Protocol._enqueue                                     
      (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)",
     "Protocol.handshake 
      (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)",
     "Connection.connect 
      (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)",
     "Connection._implyConnect 
      (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:461:10)",
     "Connection.query 
      (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:206:8)",
     "/var/task/db-write-lambda.js:52:12",
     "getOrCreateEventTypeId (/var/task/db-write-lambda.js:51:12)",
     "exports.dbWrite (/var/task/db-write-lambda.js:26:9)"
   ]
 }
```

Amongst the references already reviewed:

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221928
  (the invocation ID in CloudWatch is different on all timeout cases)
- pretty much every post in this list: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=aws+lambda+timeouts+to+RDS

In summary, the fact that these timeouts are **intermittent** makes this an issue that is totally confusing. AWS support has stated that `NodeJS-mysql` is a third-party tool, and is *technically* not supported, but I know folks are using this technique.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you are getting consistent timeouts, does restarting the database (and thus dropping all connections) fix it?

Comment: I have not tried that, but will do so. My thought was, because there were a very limited number of connections open (2), it shouldn't be the root cause. Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that you've given the database too small an instance, and it's got itself into a bad state. Check the CPU usage vs what you expect from zero load. 7% might be ok, but maybe 40% indicates a problem.

Comment: CPU usage never went above 2% at any point.

Comment: Oh well, at least you've eliminated one cause.

Comment: Running into the same issue and it's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that the RDS connections are not exhausted, there is a possibility that the lambda running into a particular subnet is always failing to connect to db. I am assuming that the RDS instances and lambdas are running in separate subnets. One way to investigate this is to check flow logs.

Go to EC2 -> Network interfaces -> search for lambda name -> copy eni ref and then go to VPC -> Subnets -> select the subnet of lambda -> Flow Logs -> search by eni ref.

If you see "REJECT OK" in your flow logs for your db port means that there is missing config in Network ACLs.

Comment: I, unfortunately did not enable flow logs for the Network Interface, will will follow that path now. Thank you!

Comment: Suken, good suggestion on using Flow Logs to help debug this issue.

Comment: Flow logs solved an issue like this for us, we has used a standard ACL setup for access from the DB back to Lambda and this was using the Linux ephemeral port range instead of the Lambda one.  So it was blocking some not not all connections https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports

Comment: Suken, just wanted to say thanks - I did not need flow logs, just by reading first two sentences, I knew this was the issue I had, but it would have taken me hours to figure it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Updating this issue: It turns out that the issue was related to the fact that the database connection was being made within the handler! Due to the asynchronous nature of Lambda and Node, this was the culprit for the intermittent timeouts.

Here's the revised code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const database = getConnection();

exports.dbWrite = (events, context, callback) => {

   database.connect(function (err) {
     if (err) {
          console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
          return;
     }

     console.log('connected !');
});

db.end();


function getConnection() {
   let db = mysql.createConnection({
       host: process.env.DB_HOST,
       user: process.env.DB_USER,
       password: process.env.DB_PASS,
       database: process.env.DB_NAME
   });

   console.log('Host: ' + process.env.DB_HOST);
   console.log('User: ' + process.env.DB_USER);
   console.log('Database: ' + process.env.DB_NAME);

   console.log('Connecting to ' + process.env.DB_HOST + '...');

   return db;
}
```