# RDS MySQL Connection Timeout Over Heroku to AWS Peering Connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I'm seeing an intermittent connection timeout when trying to establish a connection from a Heroku [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) to a MySQL RDS instance over Heroku's [Private Space Peering Connection](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-space-peering). The error is a `ETIMEDOUT` error using the node [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) library. It occurs at a frequency of about 1/100 attempts with no pattern as to time of day. It's also worth noting a few of the following:

- This is a staging environment and has minimal traffic so the RDS metrics are mostly flat. Resource contention is likely not the issue. CPU hovers at 1%, IOPS are negligible, connection count is <10, storage and memory are over-provisioned.
- This error only started happening when I switched to using the peering connection as opposed to connecting to the database over the public internet.
- I do not see this error when using connection pooling on longer running processes.
- MySQL error logs are clean

These are the potential issues I've investigated and ruled out:

- VPC routes exist for all RDS subnets using 10.0.0.0/16 (Heroku CIDR) via the correct peering connection
- Network ACLS applied at subnet level are ANY/ANY for all RDS subnets
- RDS allows ingress traffic via 10.0.0.0/16 (Heroku CIDR)
- DNS resolution works across the peering connection

The current MySQL connection configuration is using the default 10000 connection timeout. I'm hesitant to raise this without understanding the root cause because 10s should be plenty to establish a connection. Here is the code for connecting and tearing down the connection:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

// Heroku dyno boots up via the scheduler add-on

const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    timezone: '+00:00',
    dateStrings: ['DATE', 'DATETIME'],
    decimalNumbers: true,
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    port: parseInt(process.env.MYSQL_PORT, 10),
    ssl: fs.readFileSync('...', 'utf8')
});

// Do some work

await connection.end();

// Heroku dyno is torn down
```

It's difficult to get insight into the Heroku private space side of things because it's so abstracted but has anyone seen this kind of issue?

**UPDATE 1**

Was able to get a few tools installed on the one-off dynos and could successfully telnet and connect with the mysql client DESPITE getting a timeout from the node mysql lib. So it looks like the node mysql2 lib is timing out while running these commands do not. Any reason why that would be the case?

```
# prints Connected to [HOST]. Escape character is '^]'.
$ echo -e '\x1dclose\x0d' | telnet ${process.env.MYSQL_HOST} ${process.env.MYSQL_PORT}

# prints 8.0.17
$ echo "SELECT VERSION() AS version" | mysql -h ${process.env.MYSQL_HOST} -u ${process.env.MYSQL_USER} -p${process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've combed through flow logs for the RDS ENI around when we see a timeout and I see traffic coming from the IP of the machine that experienced the timeout. That confirms the traffic from debug `telnet <HOST> <PORT>` and `mysql -h <HOST> ...` commands are going through correctly.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656202/intermittent-timeouts-between-aws-lambda-and-rds maybe enabling some logs you could debug the problem better.

Comment: I've enabled and gone through the flow logs for the RDS ENI and haven't found any REJECTs. Around the times of connection timeout there are logs with successful connections (likely the telnet/mysql client execution) from the correct source IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hardly a satisfying answer but given the black box nature of Heroku it's all we get. Our database was hosted in a different region than our Heroku dynos. Colocating them in the same AWS region resolved the issue.